# How to classify the equation $\frac{dy}{dx} + x^{2}y = xe^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following "homework" problem:

> Classify each of the following differential equations as ordinary or
>   partial differential equations;  state the order of the equation; and
>   determine whether the equation under consideration is linear or
>   nonlinear.

1. $\frac{dy}{dx}+x^2y=x*e^x$

Looking at the back of the book, I already know that the answer is as follows:

- Ordinary Differential Equation
- First Order
- Linear

But I am trying to come to my own determination of the answers.  **Here's my analysis so far:**

### Ordinary/Partial

If $x$ is the independent variable and $y$ is the dependent variable, then I can confidentily say the equation doesn't call for any partial derivatives (also it doesn't contain any $\partial$ which seems to designate a partial derivative by convention).

### Order

The order seemed to be relatively straight forward given the following definition:

> The order of the highest ordered derivative involved in a differential
>   equation is called the order of the differential equation.

Taking $\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}$ where $n$ is the order, the only term that contains a derivative is $\frac{dy}{dx}$ which can also be seen as $\frac{d^1y}{dx^1}$. It is my understanding that ONLY derivatives are considered when assessing order.

### Linearity

Here's where I'm having some trouble and leads to my specific question, **do these type of equations need to be manipulated in oder to identify linearity?**  Seems in this specific case there's some room for reducing or maninpulating the equation.

The definition for linearity is give as such:

> A linear ordinary equation of order $n$, in the dependent variable $y$
>   and the independent variable $x$, is an equation that is in, or can be
>   expressed in, the form
>
> $a_0(x) \frac{d^ny}{dx^n} + a_1(x)\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}} + ... + a_{n-1}(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+a_n(x)y=b(x)$
>
> where $a_0$ is not identically zero.

I understand what the term linear means and is often in terms of line with some slope ($y=mx+b$).  But the definition is giving me trouble in respect to this problem.  At first it looks like it addresses any derivative to order $n$, but then $n$ appears as a part of the function's subscript. Either way, nothing about this definition looks linear to me.  **How does this definition apply to being linear?**

Please excuse how verbose this question is, I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything. Thanks!

Comment: It is linear because $\frac{d(y+y')}{dx}+x^2(y+y')=(\frac{dy}{dx}+x^2y)+(\frac{dy'}{dx}+x^2y')$ and $\frac{d(\lambda y)}{dx}+x^2(\lambda y)=\lambda(\frac{dy}{dx}+x^2y)$.

Comment: By the way it is also inhomogenous since $\frac{dy}{dx}+x^2y\neq 0$

Comment: It is linear because it is precisely of the shape described in the definition, with $n=1$.

Comment: Where does the $y+y'$ come from?